# ¿Cómo recibir un fichero desde un html?

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs

Estoy intentando recibir un fichero de extensión (.xlsx) por un input html que tiene este aspecto:

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" accept=".xlsx"/>
<button id="upload" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ft_uploadFile()">Upload</button>
```

Esto tengo entendido que debo recibirlo usando "Js", y que cuando se pulse el botón "Upload", llamar a una función donde pueda obtener el fichero desde el input, pero no sé cómo hacerlo, he intentado lo siguiente:

```
function ft_uploadFile() {
    alert("Uploading file...");
    var file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "/upload", true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            alert("File uploaded");
        }
    }
}
```

Pero cuando pulso el botón Upload, no pasa absolutamente nada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes realizarlo de diferentes formas, lo que a mí me ha funcionado es lo siguiente:

En primera instancia creo unas funciones para mantenerlo fácil de leer y entendible, además de que va facilitar entender el funcionamiento del evento.

```
function init() {
  document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
}

function handleFileSelect(event) {
  const reader = new FileReader()
  reader.onload = handleFileLoad;
  reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0])
}

function handleFileLoad(event) {
  console.log(event);
  document.getElementById('fileContent').textContent = event.target.result;
}
```

event.target.Files[0] es lo que contiene el archivo realmente, tal vez quieras validar que no esté vacío, o en su defecto, si aceptas más de 1 recorrerlo con un ciclo.

El HTML de referencia podría ser así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
  <input id="file" type="file" name="file" />
  <pre id="fileContent"></pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).